# "php not inserting in to mysql server in xampp"

Tags: php, html, sql

"I have read a lot of problem been solved in stackoverflow similar to my problem, and have seen a lot of example, yet still  my code is not inserting in to mysql. however if i hard feed the php it would insert. my info is coming as submit from html post.I have good server connection and also connection to the database, can any one help me if i miss any thing. here is my code below."

```php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db="image";


// Create connection

$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db); // Establishing Connection with Server
if (!$connection) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
else{
      echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$name = $_POST['name'];
$image = $_POST['image'];

echo $name;
echo $image;

if($name !=''||$image !=''){
//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO image (id, name, imagename) VALUES ('NULL', '$name', '$image')");
echo "Data Inserted successfully...!!";
}
else{
echo "Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!";
}
}
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server
?>


<form action = "test2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>name: </label><input type="text" name="name" />
    <label>File: </label><input type="text" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

" i expect output of 5/2 to be 2.5"

Comment: welcome to SO please read [MCVE] , add what error you get with your code trials

Answer (score 0):

Write the name for submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

then in php file

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL

}
```

this if statement will run

Comment: but i thought that is what am doing in the HTML by setting up this form

Comment: "<form action = "test2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>name: </label><input type="text" name="name" />
    <label>File: </label><input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>"

Comment: as you can see the <input type="submit" name="submit" />  i thought here am define type and also name for calling in php script.

Answer (score 0):

you not given `name` attribute to `button` so give `name="submit"` and if you want to upload file then change `type="file"`

```php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db="image";


// Create connection

$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db); // Establishing Connection with Server
if (!$connection) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
else{
      echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$name = $_POST['name'];
$image = $_POST['image'];

echo $name;
echo $image;

if($name !=''||$image !=''){
//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO image (id, name, imagename) VALUES ('NULL', '$name', '$image')");
echo "Data Inserted successfully...!!";
}
else{
echo "Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!";
}
}
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server
?>


<form action = "test2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>name: </label><input type="text" name="name" />
    <label>File: </label><input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking `isset($_POST['submit'])` but there is no input field which is posted with submit name.. you need to add the name attribute in the `submit` button. also you're not passing the `$connection` in the `mysqli_query`.

```php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db="image";


    // Create connection

    $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db); // Establishing Connection with Server
    if (!$connection) {
          die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    else{
          echo "Connected successfully"; 
        }


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $image = $_POST['image'];

    echo $name;
    echo $image;

    if($name !=''||$image !=''){
    //Insert Query of SQL
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO image (id, name, imagename) VALUES ('NULL', '$name', '$image')");
    if($query !== false){
        echo "Data Inserted successfully...!!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Query failed";
    }
    }
    else{
    echo "Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!";
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection with Server
    ?>


    <form action = "test2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>name: </label><input type="text" name="name" />
        <label>File: </label><input type="text" name="image" />
        <input type="submit" name = "submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

One more suggestion always use PDO in code to prevent SQL injection. Your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: thank you, yes you are right, am new to php coding, yet am more shell script coder, however coding for sql insertion is more complicated with shell script, yet want to use php as bridge

Comment: here even with this where pass the conncetion and sql, would have the same effect.if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo 'new record updated';
}
else
{
    echo 'no Data Inserted';
}

Comment: @eahubs Yeah.. You can do in this way too.. but there is a catch it will return mysqli_result when you do a select statement.. and in this you're only inserting so it's fine. If you will do if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) check for select statement then it will fail.. as it will not return the true while return the mysqli_result and you're checking true with strict typing..